# Weak $*$ convergence in continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Condider $D$ open bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider a sequence $f_n \in C(\overline{D})$, bounded. I want to prove that there exists a subsequence denoted again by $f_n$ such that:

- $f_n \rightharpoonup_*f\in L^\infty(\overline{D})$
- $f$ has a continuous representative $f \in C(\overline{D})$

Here is my try.

1. $f_n$ is bounded in $L^\infty$ and $L^1$ is separable, so, by Banach-Alaouglu, the first bullet point is done
2. consider the subsequence $f_n$ above. Since the space $M(\overline{D})$ of signed measures on the compact set $\overline{D}$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra is separable, and it is the dual of $C(\overline{D})$, then $f_n \rightharpoonup_*f_2\in C(\overline{D})$
3. now, let $g \in L^1$. By the first point, $\int f_ngdx \rightarrow \int fgdx$. Calling $\mu(A)=\int_Agdx$ we get that $\mu \in M(\overline{D})$ and by Radon-Nikodym $d\mu = gdx$. By point 2 we thus get $\int fgdx = \int f_2gdx$ for all $f\in L^1$ so that $f=f_2 \in C(\overline{D})$

Would this work? I am a bit unsure about the application of the results from measure theory. If the reasoning is not correct, is the claim true though, and do you have a hint on how to prove it?

Comment: The problem is to show that the limit $f$ is continuous, which it isn;t in general. Take $f_n(x) = \min(x^n,1)$ on $D=(0,2)$.

Comment: @daw But $f_2$ is continuous, so, $f$ has a continuous representative. Where do you think the error could lie, in my sketch above?

Comment: Second bullet proves weak-star convergence in measure space, which does not at all imply continuity of the limit, it implies that the limit is a measure, i.e. $f_2 \in M(D)$ ! this result is inferior to weak-star convergence in $L^\infty$.

Comment: Right, I made quite some typos. Now it should be correct @daw

Comment: But the weak * limit is by definition in $C(\overline{D})$, isn't it?

Comment: Just like the $f$ above in in $L^\infty$

Comment: No. Think again: the weak-star convergence happens in the space of measures. Above all, I provided a counter-example in my first comment.

Comment: Of course, you are right, I swapped dual and predual in the Riesz theorem